# how to make an Authorization request with my token on a website

Tags: java, spring, security, jwt, token

When I receive a Jwt token and in the postman program I make an Authorization get request Bearer token along the path "/admin" it gives me a page

I want to do the same thing, but without the postman program
My repo - https://github.com/kaivix/MiniBank/